# How to modify regular expression for matching beginning and end of a line zero or 1 time?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to create a regex with 3 capturing groups to extract information for the 4 possible case below:

```
val line1 = "127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com"
val line2 = "#127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com"
val line3 = "127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com # Comment"
val line4 = "#127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com # Comment"

val m = lineRegex.findFirstMatchIn(line2).get

line2.substring(m.start(1), m.end(1))  // Should be # or ""
line2.substring(m.start(2), m.end(2))  // Should be ssl.google-analytics.com
line2.substring(m.start(3), m.end(3)) // Should be # Comment or ""
```

I came up with:

```
val lineRegex = """(^#?).*(?:127\.0\.0\.1)\s+((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-\.]{1,63}(?<!-)\.+[A-Za-z]{2,6})\s+(#?.*)""".r
```

But it does not match line1 or line2. What do I need to change to make it work for all 4 possible cases?

Comment: Besides issue with the `\s+` (1 or more whitespaces) at the end (as Wiktor explained). It's best to also backslash that last dash in `[A-Za-z0-9-\.]`. Just to avoid that the dash would be used for a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the last group optional (i.e. `\s+(#?.*)` -> `(?:\s+(#?.*))?`) or just use a `*` quantifier with the last `\s`:

```
val lineRegex = """(^#?).*(?:127\.0\.0\.1)\s+((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-\.]{1,63}(?<!-)\.+[A-Za-z]{2,6})\s*(#?.*)""".r
                                                                                               ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM0bA8/1) and a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/9srWNg).

A version with the optional group requires a null check for Group 3 (since it may come uninitialized) ([demo](https://ideone.com/TaQhBi)):

```
val lineRegex = """(^#?).*(?:127\.0\.0\.1)\s+((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-\.]{1,63}(?<!-)\.+[A-Za-z]{2,6})(?:\s+(#?.*))?""".r
//                                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
val m = lineRegex.findFirstMatchIn(line2).get
//...
if (m.group(3) != null) println(m.group(3))
```

**NOTE: You may print/use `m.group(N)` directly, no need to get the substring.**

Answer (score 1):

If it is not explicitly required to use that expensive looking RegEx, you can get desired result by processing the string very easily.

```
def processLineString(l: String): List[String] = {
  val (p1, rest) = {
    if (l.head == '#') (l.head.toString, l.tail)
    else ("", l)
  }
  val (p2, p3, p4) = rest.split(" ").toList match {
    case p2d :: p3d :: "#" :: p4d :: Nil => (p2d, p3d, "# " + p4d)
    case p2d :: p3d :: Nil => (p2d, p3d, "")
  }
  List[String](p1, p2, p3, p4)
}
```